# object HTMLCollection error in my first code

Tags: javascript, php, html

Code is below. I want to parse the tables with the id result-set of the linked URL after file_get_contents. Is this the proper way to do it? I am new to php, html and javascript, so please explain even the simplest steps. What is hard for me is to combine html, php and js and get it to work without errors.

When I save this as a php file and open it, it only says [object HTMLCollection]. Why? What is the problem here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$var = file_get_contents("link here");
// echo $var;
?>

<script>
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("result-set");
document.write(x)
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should use `DOMDocument` on the `$var` and process the document as you need to ~ `DOMXPath` might also be useful

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using Javascript to return a collection of nodes which is why you get the message "htmlCollection" but because the HTML from the remote site is NOT present in your html page it will be an empty collection anyway. You can use the method you have shown but you would need to echo the response from `file_get_contents` so that the various table elements are present in your html - it looks messy however and is not valid html.

An alternative, using `DOMDocument` and `XPath` - example.

```
    $url='http://wttv.click-tt.de/cgi-bin/WebObjects/nuLigaTTDE.woa/wa/groupPage?championship=M%C3%BCnster+16%2F17&group=275320';

    /* simple variable to branch logic */
    $clonetable=true;

    /* try to prevent errors */
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

    /* create the DOMDocument object ready to receive html from remote url */
    $dom=new DOMDocument;

    /* We need another instance of DOMDocument to clone nodes from source url */
    if( $clonetable ) $html=new DOMDocument;

    /* use some of the defined properties for libxml */
    $dom->validateOnParse=false;
    $dom->standalone=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->formatOutput=false;

    $dom->loadHTML( file_get_contents( $url ) );

    /* Capture errors */
    $parse_errs=serialize( libxml_get_last_error() );
    libxml_clear_errors();


    /* create an X-Path object ready to query the DOM */
    $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
    /* Query to find tables with given class */
    $col=$xp->query('//table[@class="result-set"]');

    /* 
        If the query succeeds, iterate through elements.
        Technically you could use 1 xpath query to find the
        table cells directly but you would have less control
        over whether or not to display items etc etc
    */
    if( $col && !empty( $col ) ){
        foreach( $col as $index => $table ){

            if( $clonetable ){

                /* Create a copy/clone of existing tables from remote page */
                $clone=$table->cloneNode(true);
                /* Add these clones to the second DOMDocument instance */
                $html->appendChild( $html->importNode($clone,true) );

            } else {

                /* Another xpath query to find the table cells and work with the data therein */
                $cells=$xp->query('tr/td',$table);

                if( $cells && !empty( $cells ) ){
                    foreach( $cells as $cell ){
                        /* do something with the table cell data */
                        echo $cell->nodeValue . '<br />';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /* Display the cloned tables as they were in original document, minus CSS */
        if( is_object( $html ) ) echo $html->saveHTML();
    }
    if( !empty( $parse_errs ) ){
        print_r($parse_errs);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cant get the code to work. There are four "
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML():" errors in the `loadHTML` line and many notes "Notice: Use of undefined constant BR - assumed 'BR' " in the `echo $cell->nodeValue.BR;` line.

Comment: oh sorry - the `BR` is a constant I have defined locally - it's a `<br />` tag.

Comment: It works now, thanks. I will try to form a table with the data I have now, so far it is just one row for every entry.

Comment: there is a `cloneNode` function available to `DOMDocument` - You could use that to clone the entire table - I gave the above code only as example as to how you could use `DOMDocument` to access and manipulate the data in the table. As they say RTM - or in less polite circles, RTFM ~ there is great control available with the builtin functions

Comment: yes, i am finding many different functions in the php manual. the problem is that most of the time i dont know if they can help me with this code, if they are applicable and if and how to combine them with the current code.

Comment: Made  a brief edit to show how you could clone nodes and display the content in it's original form without building again in your own document.